# What is the plural of "cas" in French? It already ends in S

Tags: orthographe, pluriel

What is the plural of *cas* in French? "Case" in French is *cas* but what is "cases" in French?

Case = *Cas*

Cases = ?

Comment: Note that if you encounter *cases* in French, it's the plural of *case* "compartment, box" and Toto's rule still applies to *cas*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a general rule in French, words that end with `s` when singular don't change in the plural.

So "cases" is "cas" in French.

The same rule applies with words that end with `z` as "gaz" or `x` as "croix"